# Set a setting at runtime

Tags: c#, properties

I'm having trouble setting application properties at runtime. My application connects to a database and so I have stored the location of the database, which is used to generate the connection string.

The database is stored on a usb stick and so when plugged into different computers it checks to see if the database exists in the saved location, then if it isn't there, it prompts the user to select it in an OpenFileDialog.

I then try to store it as a setting, which gets saved while the application is open, but as soon as the application is closed the setting reverts to it's default value.

Here's how I try to set the dbLocation setting.

```
DBce_TEST2.Properties.Settings.Default.dbLocation = fileName;
```

This is how the getter and setter looks. The get part was generated by visual studio, and I added the set part which is where the problem lies (I think).

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("E:\\C# Projects\\DBce_TEST2\\TestDB2.sdf")]
public string dbLocation {
     get {
          return ((string)(this["dbLocation"]));
     }
     set
     {
          this["dbLocation"] = value; //most likely error here
     }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the property isn't enough.  You need to save it, too:

```
DBce_TEST2.Properties.Settings.Default.dbLocation = fileName;
DBce_TEST2.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: perfect! thank you, knew it would be something simple